# How to get unique values in jList?

Tags: java, excel

I have an excel database with some values like

```
PlotID  Sl_no   Species          Gbh_cm
P1       1  Cassia fistula              13
P1       2  Lagerstroemia parviflora    41
P1       3  Lagerstroemia parviflora    59
P2      84  Shorea robusta              97
P2      85  Shorea robusta             101
P2      86  Shorea robusta             103
P2      87  Terminalia tomentosa       227
P2      88  Terminalia tomentosa        83
P2      89  Terminalia tomentosa       226
P2      90  Terminalia tomentosa        88
```

I want to display distinct values of species in my jList.When I run my code I get distinct values of all species except Terminalia tomentosa which is the last species of my excel database. This species come two times.
My code is:

```
sql1="select distinct Species from [Data$] where Plot_ID = ? ";
        pst1=con.prepareStatement(sql1);
        pst1.setString(1, tmp);
        //pst1.setString(2, tmp);
        rs5=pst1.executeQuery(); 

        while(rs5.next())            
        {
            species=rs5.getString("Species");
            System.out.println(species);
            dlm1.addElement(species);
        }

        listSPECIES.setModel(dlm1);
```

Comment: This is not a solution, but try debugging with - 1) remove where clause from query and try, and 2) try selecting distinct Sl_no instead of selecting distinct Species in your query. Then see what happens

Comment: It was a problem in my excel and I corrected it.